# What is the treatment for Pathological Liars?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I know someone who I believe to be a pathological lier. The sow fiction into almost everything they say to some degree and when pressed make up a more elaborate lie to cover the fiction. Often the lies are gross exaggerations with some truth to them. I read that %40  of people diagnosed with PL have some sort of neurological disorder, and that on average they are below the median IQ. This individual is very intelligent and to my knowledge has no neurological disorders. I want to get this person help but the biggest lie they tell is that don't lie). Is there treatment for for PL medical or cognitive?

Comment: Punish them for lying and reward for telling the truth I guess